# Android Facebook Open Graph post not working

Tags: android, facebook-opengraph, android-facebook

I am trying to post an open graph story through my app and this is the code I am using :

```
OpenGraphObject trip = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("project_name:city");
                    trip.setProperty("url", "http://samples.ogp.me/670838023004167");
                    trip.setProperty("title", "Sample City");
                    trip.setProperty("description", "");
                    trip.setType("project_name:city");
                    OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
                    action.setProperty("trip", trip);
                    action.setProperty("previewPropertyName", trip);
                    //action.setType("project_name:city");
                    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(ShareTripActivity.this, action, "me/project_name:travel", "trip")
                            .build();
                    shareDialog.present();
                    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

I get the dialog generated for a few second but then it closes and returns to the previous screen before the user can do anything. It gives an error saying "Failed to generate preview for user" , but the app does not crash. What could be the issue?
Thanks

Comment: what do you, exactly, want to do?

Comment: I want to display an open graph post dialog which allows the user to share to Facebook.

Comment: is there a custom property there? for which you will need to use "object.getData().setProperty()" instead of "object.setProperty()" directly

Answer (score 0):

I saw a solution in a different thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18716997/529518

the solution is that the action word has to match the one that facebook set perfectly. 
The only way to see this is at the open graph code generator for types.

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{app-id}/opengraph/types

You can find it at the above link at the action types section.

Now, take the namespace and action type that facebook provided and replace it with "appnamespace:action" below.

```
OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
        action.setProperty("object", "http://object.url");

FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "appnamespace.action", "object")
                .build();
uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

Answer (score -1):

its deprecated with working..

```
private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);

public void postToWall() {
    // post on user's wall.
    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: So in this where do I create the opengraph object and action? Where do I assign the properties? Can you explain ?

Comment: its not using opengraph..and even if you are using opengraph..you can add this code where you want to perform post on facebook...without any change in your previous code

Comment: This won't work because this is the code for a normal dialog and the deprecated function is that of opengraph. If i simply replace, then I won't get the opengraph dialog.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

WebDialog feedDialog = (
    new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
        Session.getActiveSession(),
        params))
    .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values,
            FacebookException error) {
            if (error == null) {
                // When the story is posted, echo the success
                // and the post Id.
                final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                if (postId != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // User clicked the Cancel button
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Publish cancelled", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                // User clicked the "x" button
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Publish cancelled", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Generic, ex: network error
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Error posting story", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    })
    .build();
feedDialog.show();
```

}

Use this code.. it shares data to facebook as a graph story!

Comment: How is this working ? You haven't used any open graph object or action here.